Adding one entity to Multiple Pop up windows - WPF
I would like to know if it is possible to add an entity to multiple windows at once. An Example would be that I have 3 pop up windows for different kinds of training. I scan myself (barcode) and the behavior I am expecting is my name to be automatically be associated in those 3 pop up windows that are open. How would I approach that? Is there a helpful link that you can provide that could help me?

Simply share the same DataContext  amongst  your popups.

I would have put all the relevant underlying data in an ViewModel, then share that ViewModel between the windows.
xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:TestApplication.ViewModels"
    <Window.DataContext>
        <vm:ViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>

Then depending on how you create these additional windows, you could do something like
Window window = new();
window.DataContext = this.DataContext;

If you don't know how to utilize ViewModels, I would recommend starting there. Community Toolkit MVVM is fairly straightforward and easy to learn and use.

Thank you for that. I would try this method and see how it goes
